# not able to access metamask account, even if i manually connect website

Tags: web3js, ethereumjs

I am trying to connect my website to metamask manually, still, I'm not able to access the account.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ZyVK.png)

I'm able to read data from the smart contract but when I call a function which changes the state it gives an error

[image]

`enter code here`

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <body>
       <input type="text" id= "i1"> 
        <button id ="b1">set</button>
        <button id="b2">show</button>
  
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.js" integrity="sha256-DrT5NfxfbHvMHux31Lkhxg42LY6of8TaYyK50jnxRnM=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/@metamask/detect-provider/dist/detect-provider.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/ethereum/web3.js@1.2.7/dist/web3.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

window.addEventListener('load', async () => {

  let abi = [
    {
        "inputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "_data",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "name": "w",
        "outputs": [],
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "r",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    }
];
  let add = "0x73FaC9D61321EB3E68F20846bD35644B0D997e10"



/// var  web3 = new Web3();
 //web3 = new Web3( Web3.currentProvider);
 
 
 
 web3 = new Web3('https://rpc-mumbai.matic.today')

  const mycontract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, add);
   
  

   console.log(mycontract);
   const acc = await web3.eth.getAccounts()
   console.log(acc);
   

   $("#b1").click( async function(){
        var str = $("#i1").val();
      await mycontract.methods.w(str).send({from: "0x70aF29f754988473fcAbA6E01AbfbafF871046d1"});
         
         
    });

    $("#b2").click( async function(){
       
       var x = await mycontract.methods.r().call();
       alert(x);
         
         
    });
   
   

})
</script> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: though im able to call read only function but when i call function which changes the states it give"his error --> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Returned error: unknown account  screenshot of the error-->  [link](https://i.postimg.cc/768qphMq/Screenshot-150.png)

Answer (score 0):

The http- server was not on , that's why was not able to access account. Now it's working